# how to flash image.bin with uboot using serial or tftp

Tags: linux, flash

Hello I have a 4G LTE router which is blocked. and I have already dumped the partitions before via `telnet` from another device of the same model.

```
    U-Boot 2010.09 (Sep 06 2016 - 10:08:39)GCT GDM7243



Build Info:

  date: 2016/09/06-10:08:44

  user: root@ubuntu-will

  svnr: 

  src: /home/will/DEVELOPMENT/LTE_Router/B5328_FDD/SDK/work/uboot

  ver: 0.46e



DRAM:  128 MiB (wbd-p2)

NAND:  Built-in ECC Nand
maf_id : 0x00000098, dev_id : 0x000000a1
Pagesize : 2Kbytes
Address cycle : 4
128 MiB
Bad block table found at page 65472, version 0x01
Bad block table found at page 65408, version 0x01
nand_read_bbt: Bad block at 0x000006000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:    001cc910 Realtek8211  PHYCR1: 0000211c  Rx delay: 0x00802300 
    PHYCR2:0x842  mii0
Hit ENTER key to stop autoboot:  5  4  3  2  1  0 
GPIO RESET KEY OFF
00420000
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0xffffffff
magic       : 0xffffffff
timstamp    : 0xffffffff
data chksum : 0xffffffff
data size   : 0xffffffff
---------------------
image header magic is invalid
00440000
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0xa6160741
magic       : 0xcafebabe
timstamp    : 0x00000003
data chksum : 0xf314f304
data size   : 0x0001ffdc
---------------------
cmnnv current block is : 1
pesifwcheck=1
Erasing Nand...

Erasing at 0x80000 --  25% complete.
Erasing at 0xa0000 --  50% complete.
Erasing at 0xc0000 --  75% complete.
Erasing at 0xe0000 -- 100% complete.
Writing to Nand... done

boot from part_idx: 2
do_check_partition() type:linux2, ---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
no valid header(0)
There are no valid headers
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
no valid header(1)
There are no valid headers
Erasing Nand...

Erasing at 0x80000 --  25% complete.
Erasing at 0xa0000 --  50% complete.
Erasing at 0xc0000 --  75% complete.
Erasing at 0xe0000 -- 100% complete.
Writing to Nand... done

---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
no valid header(0)
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
no valid header(2)
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
---------------------
hdr chksum  : 0x00000000
magic       : 0x00000000
timstamp    : 0x00000000
data chksum : 0x00000000
data size   : 0x00000000
---------------------
  ## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at d05fffc0 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.10.0-uc0
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    2317840 Bytes = 2.2 MiB
   Load Address: d0600000
   Entry Point:  d0600000
   Verifying Checksum ... Bad Data CRC
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

If I try to boot from TFTP the image loads just fine and everything is working.

I flashed the `linux.bin` image to the respective partition but I don't know what I need to do to be able to get the device working again. Maybe flashing from U-Boot will get it to work .

Here's the boot process information from TFTP:

```
    Using mii0 device
TFTP from server 192.168.0.10; our IP address is 192.168.0.1
Filename 'linux.bin'.
Load address: 0xd05fffc0
Loading: *##T ###############################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     ##########################
done
Bytes transferred = 4194304 (400000 hex)
Automatic boot of image at addr 0xD05FFFC0 ...
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at d05fffc0 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.10.0-uc0
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    2317840 Bytes = 2.2 MiB
   Load Address: d0600000
   Entry Point:  d0600000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
gipc-protocol address: d4880010
ipc config: 00000004
  router-device
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
ipc magic=0x40540103(12)
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010003
```

Here's the partition layout:

```
device nand0 <gdm7243>, # parts = 17
 #: name        size        offset      mask_flags
 0: u-boot              0x00080000  0x00000000  0
 1: env                 0x00080000  0x00080000  0
 2: rev0                0x00100000  0x00100000  0
 3: ltenv               0x00100000  0x00200000  0
 4: wmnv                0x00100000  0x00300000  0
 5: cmnnv               0x00100000  0x00400000  0
 6: cmnnv2              0x00100000  0x00500000  0
 7: rev1                0x00400000  0x00600000  0
 8: linux               0x00400000  0x00a00000  0
 9: linux2              0x00400000  0x00e00000  0
10: rootfs              0x01e00000  0x01200000  0
11: rootfs2             0x01e00000  0x03000000  0
12: tk                  0x00500000  0x04e00000  0
13: tk2                 0x00500000  0x05300000  0
14: customize           0x00080000  0x05800000  0
15: log                 0x00280000  0x05880000  0
16: update              0x02000000  0x05b00000  0

active partition: nand0,0 - (u-boot) 0x00080000 @ 0x00000000

defaults:
mtdids  : nand0=gdm7243
mtdparts: mtdparts=gdm7243:512k(u-boot),512k(env),1m(rev0),1m(ltenv),1m(wmnv),1m(cmnnv),1m(cmnnv2),4m(rev1),4m(linux),4m(linux2),30m(rootfs),30m(rootfs2),5m(tk),5m(tk2),512k(customize),2560k(log),32m(update)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This is borderline off-topic. But I sympathize, having been there. Have you checked the (U-Boot) environment? Typically the checksum will be stored there. Try to set the checksum value on the "bricked" device to the value of the working one (assuming that's the kernel you are trying to boot). I may be completely wrong here, but I have had devices working like that. The checksum is just that: a way to check the integrity of the kernel image, not primarily tamper-proofing a device. Alternatively try U-Boot's `crc32` command on the address at which you loaded the kernel.

Comment: For showing the environment, try `printenv` and be sure that you have a valid U-Boot image (the `file` command may be of help). `setenv` and `saveenv` can be used to manipulate the environment and save your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kernel_load_addr=0xd0600000
filesize=400000
```

then reset the device . it should be working.

```
Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
gipc-protocol address: d4880010
ipc config: 00000004
  router-device
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010001
ipc magic=0x40540103(12)
s-ch_enabled: 0x10010003
```

Still the issue persist after the second reboot. 
if I reboot after typing these commands the device actually boots up normally but if i restart a second time the error will reappear again . still something to investigate on the problem.